# assembling brackets and front crankset: how many spacers and orientation

Tags: crankset, front, installation

Recently I bought a [Bull's Black Adder 1 26 Inch frame](http://www.zweirad-stadler.com/shop/bulls/bulls-mtb-rahmen-black-adder-1.html,a28700) and quite some time ago got a present Shimano Deore Lx FC M-583 crankset (brackets included). I know they are not a perfect match, but still would like to assemble together.

Question: (1) What's the orientation of the brackets?

Question: (2) How many spaces on the left and the right side do I need to put? There are 4 spacers that came together with the crankset..

Comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cup marked L goes on the left-hand side of the frame (the non-drive side) and consequently the cup marked R goes on the right-hand side. Make sure you tighten the cups in the correct direction (the drive side cup is reverse threaded) and be sure not to cross thread the frame.

As for the spacers, I presume that the frame has a bottom bracket width of 73 mm (although you should measure it to be sure), and you're going to use a front derailleur that clamps on to the seat tube. In that case, the [Shimano service instructions for FC-M583](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Deore-LX/SI_6JXFE_002/SI_6JXFE_002_En_v1_m56577569830638259.pdf) state that you should use one 2.5 mm spacer between the frame and the drive-side cup.